# Customize error page 404

Tags: apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0

I am running a rest api server using tomcat.
I am trying to make a call:

localhost:8080/�script�alert%28�XSS�%29�%2Fscript�/users

and I am getting this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /ï¿½scriptï¿½alert(ï¿½XSSï¿½)ï¿½/scriptï¿½/users was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

I want to customize this message that the url will not be in the message.
I am not sure who is generating the response, is it apache? tomcat? jersey?

I already tried to add error mapping to web.xml but it did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was acctualy on apache level and not on tomcat level as I thougth.
In order to override apache error:
[How to Override Apache error pages](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's the error page generated by Tomcat. You can disable it and just send the status code instead of an error page. To do that, you need to set the following property to `true`

> [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR)
>
> Whenever response status is `4xx` or `5xx` it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific Response implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code (e.g. servlet `error-page` configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container Response object.
>
> If property value is true the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`.
>
> Type of the property value is `boolean`. The default value is `false`.

You can set it in your `ResourceConfig` subclass constructor by just calling `property(key, value)`. Or if you are using a web.xml, just set it as an init-param. In a web.xml, you will need to use the String version

> `jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError`